# MongoDB: index to speed up querying not null fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Let's suppose I have a `webPages` collection in **mongoDB** with following document structure inside:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    url: String,
    title: String,
    links: [ComplexObject]
}
```

where `ComplexObject` is a complex object, with fields and lists inside (details are not important).

Question: what type of index & query combination should I use to be able to query those documents where `links` field is not `null`?

**Note** that collection has millions of documents, so the query has to use an index, otherwise it will be slow.

**Also note** that if not necessary, I don't want to have an index on the field `links` (besides the index which speeds up the non-null query) as it can be expensive/big and I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query `link:[ComplexObject]` contains a complex object and have one to many relationships.

if it is complex you should go for a new collection referencing a root collection, because increase in size of single object of collection will slow down you query eventually. and of course it will be difficult to achieve what is desired.

Eg:

#### webPages collection

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    url: String,
    title: String,
}
```

#### links collection

```
{
 _id: ObjectId,
 webpage_id: ObjectId // indexed
 ....
}
```

#### Your Question:

what type of index & query combination should I use to be able to query those documents where links field is not null ?

Answer: in new approach i don't think you have to check for null object.

but for older approach you can go for `$exists` keyword in simple queries OR `$ifNull pipeline` with `$size pipeline` in aggregation.
index like compound index will help a lot in your structure.

Note: Do not store null value in property either `$set` it or `$unset` it, then $exists will work.

Eg.

#### compound index

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "links.property1": 1, "links.property2": 1 } );
```

#### $exists

```
webPages.find({ $exists: { link: true }});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

#### aggregation

to check null values aggregation has a pipeline call `$ifNull`

```
webPages.aggregate([
{
        $addFields: {
            isExists: {
                $ifNull: [ "$links", 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            // validate isExists
        }
    }
]);
```

#### to check if array is empty

webPages.aggregate([[
    {
        $addFields: {
            arrayLength: {
                $size: "$links"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            // validate arrayLength
        }
    }
]);

there are alot way to handle such stuff.

Comment: I have good reasons to store documents as I wrote, I don't want to split. I just want an index to be used when I query the field whether that's null or not. You did not provide an index definition in your answer, so I guess (without trying) this won't answer my question in this format.

Comment: if you want to create index for your structor , you can for compound index.
```db.collection.createIndex( { "links.property1": 1, "links.property2": 1 } );```